# When and how to use !important CSS property in a bookmarklet with cross domains?

Tags: php, javascript, css, api, bookmarklet

I have a `bookmarklet` and recently I have changed the `CSS` properties, using [cleanslate css](https://github.com/premasagar/cleanslate) because the bookmarklet design was not the same on third party websites, when used.

This CSS file, should reset all the properties of all the tags within a specific tag, and it does that, but when I need to manipulate the settings, I can't;

```
<div class="mainclass">
<div id="login">a</div>
<div id="form">b</div>
<div id="details">c</div>
</div>
```

I have many forms, which I hide and unhide at specific actions, like: I show the login form, if the user in not logged in, I show the the detail form, if the user is logged in and if I know the history of a URL, and other forms;

So, if I set the `div id details display` property to `block`, and the rest to `none`, and then try to set all to `none` and the `div id form display` property to `block`, the `css` it doesn't do anything, but I can see that the `javascript` runs the actions

This CSS should do the job, but because I used the !important property on all the tags properties, I can't set from JavaScript new values to properties, like:

```
document.getElementById("form").style.display = "none";
```

[image]

in this image, I use the old CSS, a reset method was used, and also, the js code worked fine, but the design was not the same on third party websites

in the actual project, the design is the same on all the third party websites, but the js code can't set CSS properties

Comment: You shouldn't ever have to use `!important`.

Comment: From your title: "when and how to use `!important`" -> never

Comment: but if i dont use !important, my bookmarklet will inherit the third party css properties

Comment: Actually in this case it might be necessary since, if I am reading the question right, he has no control over the cascade of the third party CSS sheets. People need to read before making blanket statements. It's like so many people saying tables are bad that you see people using divs for tabular data... That being said I don't actually see a question

Comment: yes, thats it, its a cross domain app, and my app css mixes with the third party websites

Comment: i will post 2 images ... 2 sec pls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Important is a really bad idea in general and should try to be avoided as it breaks the rules of specificity in css. Is there no way you can make your css more specific to overide the current styles rather than using !importnat.

You can still apply importnant by doing some thing like this

```
element.style.setProperty("display", "none", "important");
```

Or jquery makes it quite easy

```
element.css("display","none !important");
```

But again best to just not use important

Comment: it doesnt matter in ie, what about safari, mozilla and chrome ?

Comment: it is not, now my design is the same on all third party websites, but the javascript cant control the bookmarklet design

Comment: no probs good luck with the rest off your project and remember to stay away from those important ;)